# Recode column dynamically

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I recode a column using a function that decides which name an old variable name is to be changed to, based on a passed argument?

```
library(sjstats) # has example data
library(tidyverse)
 
data(efc)

# Function to decide the name of the variable
decide_name <- function(c161sex) {
  name <- case_when(
    c161sex == 1 ~ "Male",
    c161sex == 2 ~ "Female",
    TRUE ~ "missing"
  )
  return(name)
}
```

Recode the variable dynamically depending on the returned value (each dataset will have 1 and only 1 value for the variable "c161sex")

```
efc_renamed <- efc %>%
    rename(decide_name = e42dep)
```

Comment: Please provide some test data and your expected output based on that test data.  Your sample code at the moment suggests that you are attempting to recode the values in a column, not rename the column itself.  Moreover, in your second code chunk, you appear to be assigning a value to the function you have previously defined and claiming that the argument to the function is a column in a data frame.

Comment: Use `rename_with`

Comment: @mhovd I think what the OP want is `recode`, not `rename`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `recode()`, instead of `rename()`.

```r
recode_dynam <- function(var) {
  recode(var, `1` = "Male", `2` = "Female", .default = "missing", .missing = "missing")
}
```

###### Test

```r
efc_recoded <- efc %>%
  mutate(e42dep = recode_dynam(e42dep))

efc_recoded %>%
  count(e42dep)

#    e42dep   n
# 1  Female 225
# 2    Male  66
# 3 missing 617
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `case_when`

```
fn <- function(nm) {
     case_when(nm == 1 ~ "Male", nm == 2 ~ "Female")
}
efc_new <- efc %>% 
   mutate(e42dep = fn(e42dep))
```

-checking

```
> table(efc_new$e42dep)

Female   Male 
   225     66
```